# Google Chrome crashing on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, google-chrome, memory, crash

Recently Google Chrome has started to crash constantly on OSX Yosemite.

I have been running the 64bit Dev Channel of Chrome successfully for a long time with no issues, recently it started to crash periodically and then fail to open up again without crashing. Give it a couple of hours and it does successfully load again.

Thinking it was a dev channel issue, I completely uninstalled using CleanMyMac and installed the Beta channel. This suffered the same issue, so again I completely uninstalled the beta and installed the Stable channel.

This too constantly crashes and then crashes immediately on re-launch.

I am running a mid 2013 Macbook Air with 4gb RAM.
OSX Yosemite 10.10.2

Within Chrome I have minimal extensions running.
Chrome Hangouts
uBlock
JIRA Capture

Any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem comes from a deprecated API call in Google Chrome. You can use [this automator script](http://loganisa.ninja/#download) to fix the problem, until Google releases a new version of Chrome. Mor infos and alternate instructions [here](http://9to5mac.com/2014/11/30/google-chrome-crashes-hard-with-mac-os-10-10-2-beta-heres-the-fix/)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

you might just need more ram, or there is a specific setting somewhere on your mac where when an app like chrome is taking up a lot of CPU/battery power it shuts it off immediately